# Image links with ' in wordpress replaced with %E2%80%99. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, server, phpmyadmin

I recently moved hosts and one of the things I am dealing with, is that the images don't load for some posts. And the similarity between all of them is that it contains a " ' " character, that automatically translates to  %E2%80%99 in link. SO something like Cat'stail.jpg can be Cat %E2%80%99stail.jpg . How do I fix this? The images dont load cause it says it doesn't exist on the link, as it translates to the other thing.. The database is in utf8mb4 format. I am new to this and don't know anything. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using page builder then the simplest way is re-selecting the images in the builder and update the page. If you have a custom theme then I will suggest you to manually change the image name, because as a good practice you should not use "'" in the image names.